# how to display the contents of a tab in the workspace of Jtabbedpane?

Tags: swing, netbeans, jtabbedpane

i'v put a jpanel on the tab of Jtabbedpane which is at the left side ,nw when the tab is clicked i want to display labels and textfields in the workspace of the tabbedpane,plz hlp.

Comment: if any given answer solves your problem then please accept one of them. Remember there is not point of leaving a question open if it is solved. All good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do exactly as @7SpecialGems says (+1 for that).
Here is an example showing how exactly it can look like in code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JTabbedPaneSample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createGUI();    
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGUI() throws HeadlessException
    {
        JPanel oi1 = new JPanel();
        oi1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        oi1.add(new JLabel("Label 1"));
        JPanel oi2 = new JPanel();
        oi2.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        oi2.add(new JLabel("Label 2"));
        oi2.add(new JTextField("TextField 1"));     
        JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
        tp.addTab("Oi1", oi1);
        tp.addTab("Oi2", oi2);          
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(tp);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(contentPane);
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Good luck, Boro.

Answer (score 2):

When you say 'workspace of the tabbedpane' I think you are referring to your JPanel?

You must attach the JLabels and JTextfields to the JPanel using JPanel.add() before you add the JPanel to the JTabbedPane.

Comment: If this answer solved the problem, don't forget to mark it as correct (by clicking the 'tick' beside the post.